# How to check Kafka consumer state

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have Kafka High level consumer.

```
public class KafkaHighLevelConsumer implements Runnable {
    private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
    private final List<String> topics;
    private final int id;

    public KafkaHighLevelConsumer(int id,
                        String groupId,
                        List<String> topics,BlockingQueue<String> storyQueue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.topics = topics;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9091");
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            consumer.subscribe(topics);

            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("partition", record.partition());
                    data.put("offset", record.offset());
                    data.put("value", record.value());
                    System.out.println(this.id + ": " + data);
                }
            }
        } catch (WakeupException e) {
            // ignore for shutdown
        }finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        consumer.wakeup();
    }
}
```

The consumer works fine, but I need to monitor the state of consumer. 
Why don't we have Exception if server ip or port is incorrect?

If I change port to some incorrect `props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9091");` to `props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:100500");` I still can't get any exception.

I would like to know if I successfully connected to Kafka or not! Is it possible to handle such case?

I use such Maven deps

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could use kafka-consumer-groups.sh to see topic consumers and its states

Comment: There is no exception, because the client assumes that the broker might just be down. Client would connect to the broker, if it goes online.

Answer (score 1):

According to the client documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> It will transparently handle the failure of servers in the Kafka cluster

The library cannot tell the difference between a temporary failure, a permanent failure or a misconfiguration. So it considers every failure to be "retryable", and does exactly this, retries forever, never returning an error.

This is a workaround to check the state of the connection: Ask for some information that is guaranteed to return, wait for some reasonable time and if nothing returns then you know that the connection has some problem:

```
int CONNECTION_TEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 10; // or whatever is appropriate for your environment

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable testTask = consumer::listTopics;

Future future = executor.submit(testTask);
try {
    future.get(CONNECTION_TEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException te) {
    consumer.wakeup();
    throw new IOException("Could not communicate with the server within " + CONNECTION_TEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS + " seconds");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Nothing to do. Maybe a warning in the log?
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    throw new IOException("Exception while running connection test: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: Implementing this does work but on startup, there is an exception thrown: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access

Answer (score 0):

There is an event in confluent Kafka `OnError` which trigger an error whenever consumer failed to connect. Here is the code description

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Raised on critical errors, e.g. connection failures or all brokers down. Note
    //     that the client will try to automatically recover from errors - these errors
    //     should be seen as informational rather than catastrophic
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     Executes on the same thread as every other Consumer event handler (except OnLog
    //     which may be called from an arbitrary thread).
    public event EventHandler<Error> OnError;
```

> Assembly Confluent.Kafka, Version=0.11.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null